Both the [power] and [power-supply] tags exist, should they be merged?
Both the [power] tag and the [power-supply] tag exist on this site. Should they be merged?

There certainly seems to be a substantial overlap between the two tags. There are 30 questions tagged [power], 30 tagged [power-supply], and 9 questions tagged with both.
I'm inclined to agree with merging them. I'm leaning towards making [power] the default tag, and making [power-supply] a tag synonym. Thoughts/disagreement/discussion?
